# QTableview specify standard search field

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` with the following code below. It runs fine, but when I am typing the search field is always the first column, which is the number and primary key.

How can I change that the standard search field is another field, second (name) for example, even with select column on the name column or with setsort on name the standard search when typing is the first number field?

When the code is running, I can change the search column by left-clicking in the second column, but I want to achieve this programmatically.

```
class KL_browse(QDialog, ui_kl_browse.Ui_kl_browse):

    def __init__(self):
        super(KL_browse, self).__init__()
        query = QSqlQuery()

        query.exec_("""SELECT * FROM klanten""")

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("klanten")
        self.model.setSort(1, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model.select()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
     #   self.view.setColumnHidden(ID, True)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicator(1,0)
        self.tableView.selectRow(0)
        self.tableView.selectColumn(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the index as follows:

```
# index: the index of a cell in the desired column
index = tableView.model().index(0, 1)
tableView.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index, QItemSelectionModel.NoUpdate);
```